# How to query rows using Full Text Index that contains '&' in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I have a table with Full-Text indexing enabled on it and the table has some rows which contains strings such as following:

'HON & HAN'

Now I want to fetch this row using a query that uses full text indexing. Here is what I am trying (but it is fetching the rows required):

```
select * from table_name where contains(*,  '"HON*" AND "&*"') -- try # 1
select * from table_name where contains(*,  '"&*"') -- try # 2  
select * from table_name where contains(*,  '"&%"') -- try # 3
```

None of the above is working.

Comment: `contains(*, '&')` should work, as in return any row with an `&` in any column... though you probably want to use a single column, no?

Comment: Also tried contains(*, '&') but got 0 rows. Yes I want to use a single column and I have also tried with contains(columnname, '&') but no luck.

Comment: When I use where columnname like '%&%', I get all the rows I want but I want to get the data using Containts()

Comment: What does `contains(columnname, "&")` return?

Comment: Have you tried the contains on a word from which you know that it is contained in a specific column? If that doesn't work then check in the microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/search/create-and-manage-full-text-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) to see if the full-text is configured properly.

Comment: @scsimon, contains(columnname, "&") gives syntax error and contains(columnname, '&') is returning 0 rows.

Comment: @wosi, full-text is configured properly and works fine in all other cases. Only does not work with special characters like : or & or others. I have made sure that they do not exist in associated stoplist and that index is populated after the removal of these characters from stoplist.